# text-align center being affected by float elements

Tags: css

I have two float elements, right and left.

The parent element for all of them is text-align: center, margin: auto:

```html
<div class="test">
1. text
    <br>
    <span id='small_font10' style='float: left;'>999</span>
<a class='writeSComment' id='small_font10' data-id='<?php echo $id; ?>' style='cursor: pointer'>
<strong>2. text</strong>
</a>
<span id='small_font10' style='float: right;'> 
Follow me
</div>
```

```css
.test{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KRWNs/

If you see the 1. text, there's the center. The 2. text is moving ( being affected from the float elements) to the left as you can see, and are not center.

How can I make this align as the normal above (as the 1. text), without being affected by the float elements on the right and left side?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to use something other than float to stick the elements to the sides. As it is, they are behaving as they are supposed to. Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/KRWNs/2/) using absolute positioning to stick to the sides. Very long content will not honor the elements, however.

Alternatively, as seen in [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/KRWNs/3/), you need to ensure that both floats are the same width.

*The fact that the outer element is "margin auto" is irrelevant.*

Answer (score 2):

If you can't play with absolute positions, as in my case since I'm working on a page to be printed and absolute brings all the content out of the page, you can play with margins.
Simply write what you want in different lines, and then for the content you want to align right/left add a negative top margin (or bottom if you wrote it at the top).

Using Phrogz's example:

```
<div class="test">
      <div id="s0">
      1. text<br />
      2. text
   </div>
   <div id='s1'>999</div>
   <div id='s2'>Follow me</div>
</div
```

with css:

```
.test{
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    line-height: 18px;
}

#s1 { text-align: right; margin-top: -18px; }
#s2 { text-align: left;  margin-top: -18px; }
```

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chech/zJP2S/4/)

Comment: If you wrap the `position: absolute` elements inside of a `<div class="position: relative;"></div>`, they'll be contained within the relatively positioned `div`. Not sure if that helps in your exact case, but might help others wary of `position: absolute`.